# Is Message Layer Security the state of art protocol for group encryption?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I'm trying to read about Diffie Hellman (One to One) kind of protocols for group communication. Is Message Layer Security the state of art protocol for group encryption (not necessarily chat or application layer)? I found Tree Based Group Diffie Hellman as one such handshake algorithm for group encryption, but not sure about industrial application of it. Is there a RFC for the class of group encryption protocols?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9420.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested in learning more, can look at these two pointers. I'm not sure about key generation time claims like O(lg N). But understanding Ratcheting trees is important.

https://blog.quarkslab.com/secure-messaging-apps-and-group-protocols-part-2.html

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=35354226